# There was a problem verifying this package name. Facebook Android Login

Tags: facebook-authentication, android-facebook

I can't setup Facebook Login for Android.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/
The package name has a problem.
If I use a package name from an app in production status, it works.
This package is in Draft (internal testing) status.
I only can setup apps in production status?

[image]

[image]